# how to add String by value and not reference

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, strcpy

Im making a really simple TODOlist in C.

My add function takes a `char *` as its parameter. When I add it to my `char **` list of reminders, it adds the memory address of my buffer instead of the value of the string.

The problem becomes apparent when I run the given source below.

If you try to [a]dd a string, say "Test", and then issue command [p]rint, a "p" will be printed.

I understand that this is because my `list[0]` is holding a pointer to my buffer, so that when the value of buffer changes, so does the value in my list.

My C is rusty and I know that `strcpy()` might solve this issue? But is this the usual way to handle this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int size = 0;
int capacity = 50;
char **list;

void initList() {
    list = malloc( capacity * sizeof( char * ) );
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++ ) {
        list[i] = malloc( 256 * sizeof( char ) ); 
    }
}

void saveReminders() {  
}

void add( char *reminder ) {
    list[size++] = reminder;
}

void delete( int index ) {
}

void print() {
    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ )
        printf( "%s\n", list[i] );
}

void quit() {
    saveReminders();
    exit( 0 );
}

void readReminders() {
}

void helpMenu() {
    printf( "Enter a command:\n" );
    printf( "[a]dd a reminder\n" );
    printf( "[d]elete a reminder\n" );
    printf( "[p]rint all reminders\n" );
    printf( "[q]uit\n" );
}

void menu() {
    helpMenu();

    while ( 1 ) {
        char buffer[64];
        int index = 0;
        printf( "> " );
        scanf( "%s", buffer );

        if ( strcmp( buffer, "a" ) == 0 ) {
            printf( "Enter a reminder:\n> " ); 
            scanf( "%s", buffer );
            add( buffer );
            helpMenu();
        }else if ( strcmp( buffer, "d" ) == 0 ) {
            printf("Remove which index?\n> " );
            scanf( "%d", &index );
            delete( index );
            helpMenu();
        }else if ( strcmp( buffer, "p" ) == 0 ) {
            print(); 
            helpMenu();
        }else if ( strcmp( buffer, "q" ) == 0 ) {
            quit(); 
        }
    }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] ) {
    initList();  
    menu();  
}
```

Comment: You'll want to copy the string ;)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you thought it right. In your code, instead of *assigning* the pointer itself, do something like

```
 strcpy(list[size++], reminder);
```

to copy the *content*. See the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcpy) for reference.

If you'd like to have a second approach, you don't need to `malloc()` for each and every `list[i]` either. Instead of using `malloc()` and then `strcpy()`, you can directly use [`strdup()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strdup) and assign the return value to each `list[i]` to get the same result.

That said, some other points to note

- Before making use of `list[size++]`, ensure that `size` is less than `capacity`, otherwise you'll end up overrunning the allocated memory, creating [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
- `scanf( "%s", buffer );` should be `scanf( "%63s", buffer );` to prevent any possible buffer overflow.
- Always check the return value of `malloc()` for success before using the returned pointer.
- `sizeof( char )` is defined to be `1` in C standard. using it as a multiplier is *redundant*.

Comment: I was thinking of this, but was wondering if this is the most used way of solving this problem?

I guess im just asking if this is what everyone does.. thanks

Comment: The OP should also test if `size < capacity` before assigning contents to `list[size++]`.

Comment: @chqrlie Yes, fair point. Thanks for the note, I'll add that in the answer itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
list[size++] = reminder
```

use

```
strcpy(list[size++], reminder)
```

or better yet, when you scanf, remember the number of characters written, pass it to add(), then do:

```
strncpy(list[size++], reminder, len)
```

Comment: `strnpy` --> `strncpy`, and no, strncpy is not a safer version of strcpy, anyways. :)

Comment: DONT USE `strncpy`, especially with the length of the source string as an extra argument.  `strncpy` does not  `'\0'` terminate the destination buffer if the source string is longer than the length argument.  This function is **very error prone**.  Use the `strdup()` approach from Sourav Gosh's answer.